# Crashlytics Logging NSError

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have an error that is preventing some users from authenticating via OAuth. The authentication framework is returning an `NSError` in some cases that does not cause a hard crash - but I'd like to log it in some way to [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io). Is this possible? I tried logging with:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ ... };
[Crashlytics logEvent:@"authenticate.error" attributes:attributes];
```

But I can't seem to find where that event appears within the internal reporting tool.

**Edit**: I've found an equivalent to what I'm trying to do for Android (but am unsure how to do something similar in iOS) here: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. 

We announced a private beta of logged NSErrors at Twitter Flight. If you're interested in beta testing this, sign up [here.][1]


  [1]: https://get.fabric.io/labs

Comment: @MikeB Thanks for letting me know! I signed up for the beta - and will check it out.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, we're rolling out access, so stay tuned.

Comment: Just an update, this feature is now live and available to all developers.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for following up! I can't mark a comment as an answer but it sounds like this now has a definitive answer. Do you want me to create an answer or is it better if you add one?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Whoops, didn't realize it had a duplicate question. I marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CLSNSLog()` function, which acts just like `NSLog()`:

```
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
...
CLSNSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

However the data is only sent with a crash log, so you would be forced to crash, which is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks - I noticed some of those logging methods but was hoping to find a way to log without crashing the app.

Comment: @KevinSylvestre I don't believe it's possible as the only *deliverable* (so to speak) is a crash log.  The log messages are used to embellish the logs so you can see what was happening in your app prior to the crash.  I think it only delivers the last 50 or 100 of them with the crash log.